# Referenced assemblies' xml docs not copied during publish

Tags: asp.net, publish, visual-studio-2019, swashbuckle

When publishing an ASP.NET project (NET Framework 4.7.1) referencing class libraries (projects) in same solution, all of which have XML documentation generated as part of their build, only the ASP.NET project's own XML documentation file is included in published output.

These files are necessary for API docs with Swashbuckle.

This is only an issue during publish from VS, not regular builds. I'm using VS Professional 2019 v16.4.2.

**How do I include the referenced class libraries' XML documentation files as part of the publish?** It seems like such a normal use case that I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

I've tried:

- Including XML files in said projects and marking them as "Content" and "Copy always" to output dir. No change.
- Changing different publish settings, none of which seem to have any effect on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loosely based on [Sam Stephens blog post](https://blog.samstephens.co.nz/2010/10/18/msbuild-including-extra-files-multiple-builds/) I've added this to the project file, which copies all xml files to bin folder during publish. If someone comes up with a simpler approach, don't hesitate to post an answer :)

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    CopyXmlDocuments;
  </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CopyXmlDocuments">
  <ItemGroup>
    <XmlDocuments Include="$(OutDir)*.xml" />
    <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(XmlDocuments.Identity)">
      <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
    </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's all kinds of discussion about this issue.

See: 
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/795

and the follow-up issue: 
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458

But it is still not fixed. The general discussion is that these xml comments are build artifacts, and are not supported to be released when publishing. However, when using swagger, and letting it use the xml files to generate the documentation, the case to publish the artifacts is much stronger. (Since it simply doesn't work without then)

[The solution proposed](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/795#issuecomment-284029372) in the first issue is eerily similar to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I had to include the following code at the end of my project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <!-- more configuration here ... -->

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CopyXmlDocuments;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CopyXmlDocuments;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyXmlDocuments">
    <ItemGroup>
      <XmlDocuments Include="$(OutDir)*.xml" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(XmlDocuments.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files) for more info.